# Chrome crashing when opening image

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, docker

I have Docker image with google-chrome installed but it crashes when I'm opening one specific image. System Ubuntu 16.04.
I've tried bunch of chrome flags, tried to search for any chrome logs to get detailed info about it, but nothing helped.
I even tried installing Opera and Vivaldi, both of them are running on webkit, but still same problem.
Image is opening on desktops Mac/Win/Ubuntu but not in docker.
Here's the url https://fs17.fex.net/get/653006464135/204309413/519474cb/SOBAKA.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [browserless](https://github.com/joelgriffith/browserless)? I've used it for various projects (I'm the maintainer) and haven't had any issues with loading pages/pictures. Your crash might also have to do with the hardware you're running on as well, so that might be worth noting.

Comment: Thanks but i'm not sure it will fit my needs.
I'm running chrome in normal mode with xvfb, and recording video of it.